# Different behaviour of the find (parameter not correct) on *nix and windows (ming32) systems

Tags: bash, find, make, mingw

This command called from the Makefile works ok on the various *nix systems,
but fails with Windows + Mingw32 bash/makefile:

```
for a in `find libr | grep -e dll$$`; do cp $$a ${WINDIST} ; done
```

This is the error it shows in mingw32 console:

```
for a in `find libr | grep -e dll$`; do cp $a w32dist ; done
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

What the difference between most of the *nix bash and make and the mingw32's ones?

Answer (score 3):

#### FIND: Parameter format not correct

The above error is from `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe` if you call it incorrectly:

```
F:\test>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe

F:\test>find blah blah
FIND: Parameter format not correct

F:\test>
```

- You have the Windows `find` (`C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`) in your `PATH` **before** the mingw32 `find`.
- If you run `which find` in the mingw32 console it will show this.
- You need to fix your mingw32 `PATH` so that the mingw32 utilities are found first.

Answer (score 1):

### FIND: Parameter format not correct

****explanation:****

The **find** command is a powerful command used to search for files in a file system. It is available on **Cygwin** and **Windows**, but there are some differences between the two versions.

**On Cygwin**, the find command uses file system data structures to search for files. This allows it to find files quickly and efficiently, even if they are deep within a file system.

**On Windows**, the find command uses a File System Object (FSObj) to search for files. FSObj is a file system API that allows developers to create applications that work with the Windows file system.

The default is Windows, therefore when you try to run it on the command line when the operating system is Windows, it tries to run the command and encounters parameters that do not match what it expects to receive as you described:

```
`F:\test>find blah blah
FIND: Parameter format not correct`
```

To change this, you will need to change the operating system default.

You can do this via the command line as follows:

**commands:**

**1**.Check what your paths are to the find.exe file,
You will get a path for both Windows and Cygwin, with Windows being the first :

```
C:\Users\User>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe
```

**2**.Now you will see what the default operating system is:

```
`which find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`
```

**3**.use this command to set find from Cygwin befor Windows:

`set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%`

**4**.You will now see a long list of paths, and your path should be the first

`C:\Users\User\L>echo %PATH%`

**5**.Now you can do a short test to check if it works by a simple find command like:

```
`find . -type f -name *.txt`
```

If the operation returns all the files that end in txt, or it returns nothing (because you don't have any files that end like that in the current location)
You made it!
If you encounter the error again, check the steps .